# SQL INSERT INTO xxx WHERE NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into a table, but only if unique. I can do this on one criteria, but not two? I am not sure where I am going wrong? It doesn't return an error, just behaves as if there is only one criteria.

Simple table, autoID, status, type

```
INSERT INTO alarms (status, type) 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '2', '1') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT type FROM alarms WHERE (type = '1')) LIMIT 1;
```

This works fine, it will only insert if there are no other entries with a type of 1.
I would like to have multiple criteria, ie if already in the table `type=1` AND `status=5` then insert a new entry of `type=1` and `status=2`. I have tried the following (with a few variations) but cannot get it to work. No errors, just behaves as if there is only one criteria.

```
 INSERT INTO alarms (status, type) 
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT '2', '1') AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT type, status FROM alarms WHERE (type = '1' AND status = '5')) LIMIT 1;
```

Any advice? Or do I need to do a separate call to determine the multiple criteria existence.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using if/begin/end instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your input.
I would look as if the IF NOT EXIST.... WHERE will not work, apparently the WHERE statement is not compatible with mySQL. So I did it a different way!

(Entirely different approach to the issue at hand, not relative to this discussion).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries using if-begin-end instead?
The code might be simpler but, this still count as a single statement I suppose.

```
 If Not Exists( SELECT type, status FROM alarms WHERE (type = '1' AND status = '5'))
    Begin
    INSERT INTO alarms (status, type) values ("Y","type")
    End
```

Comment: Hi, this looks straight forward, but I tried this without success, I keep getting SQL syntax errors in the top line, but I can't determine how? If I just use the SELECT statement it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "HAVING"

```
INSERT INTO alarms (status, type)
SELECT status, type
FROM alarms_duplicated AS a
WHERE status = '2' AND type = '1'
GROUP BY status, type
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```